# Error `no module named flow` when trying to use Aimsun with Flow

Tags: flow-project

Repost from Flow team (question by Ziyuan G.)

---

I followed Flow's installation steps and everything went well until testing my AIMSUN installation.

AIMSUN was installed correctly, but when I tried `python examples/aimsun/sugiyama.py`, an error came up saying that `ImportError: No module named flow.controllers`.

I gave a thought and was wondering if the reason is about python version. For AIMSUN, I have to use python 2.7 in the `aimsun_flow` conda environment. But previously when I installed Flow, I was using python 3.5 in the `flow` conda environment. So I tried installing Flow again, but another error came up saying that `match for matplotlib==3.0.0`.

I realized that for python 2.7, the available version for matplotlib is 1.x.x or 2.x.x, no 3.x.x. So how could I address this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to have two conda environments. One for Flow (`flow`) and one for interacting with Aimsun API (`aimsun_flow`). You only need to install `numpy` in the the `aimsun_flow` environment and you don't need to install other packages such as `matplotlib`.

The error that you are getting might be because you didn't activate the flow environment before running the sugiyama example. Just run `source activate flow` and then run the example